# tf/tflearn incompatibility, 'tensorflow.contrib' module not found

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I use:

- tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1
- tflearn 0.3.2

I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Which recent version of tf/tflearn are compatible?

Comment: Track this [issue](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/1121).

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled tensorflow and it somehow worked

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow
```